# I can't get field from main table in json

Tags: java, json, jpa

From Postman I perform the query to the secondary table and the primary field of the parent table is not shown:

view image:

[image]

I need to see: identification_number

This is the daughter table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="accounts")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long account_number;
    private Date open_date;
    private byte status;
    private String account_type;// normalizar
    private String bank;// normalizar
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="identification_number")
    private Customer customer = new Customer();
```

This is the parent table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
public class Customer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String identification_number;
    private String identification_type;//Normalizado
    private String name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email;
    private String cell_phone_number;
    private String address;
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //private List <Account> account = new ArrayList<>();
    private Set<Account> account = new HashSet<Account>();
```

please help

Comment: Add implicit `identification_number` property to your Account entity

Comment: I think you mean doing the following: @JsonBackReference @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DETACH) private Customer identification_number = new Customer(); change in the entity account but now the account leaves it null